# I would like to create a bar chart like this using flutter, which package can I use?

Tags: flutter, bar-chart, flutter-charts

[image: Stacked Bar Chart]

I tried StackedColumn100Series but I couldn't customize it the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fl_chart package.

Here is link : https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

Answer (score 0):

You can use [syncfusion](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts) chart library it's provide your define image chart and other various type of charts.